# how to display the child nodes when we click on the parent node in ExpandableListview?

Tags: android

hi all how to implement code for ExpandableListview (i mean when i click the parent button then it has to display the child nodes) so help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this example if you already havenot,
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html